# Increasing the Spacing Between Subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using this in my first python script, and I'm clearly very new, so please be patient. I have been working on this plot for way more time than I care to admit specifically to avoid asking a question here, but I am out of ideas. I've simplified my code a bit for this post, but even still the problem persists. I need to increase the spacing of the imshow plots such that the axes and color bar values are clearly visible. Obviously in actuality all of the data is different so individual colorbar scales are necessary and the axes have negative values, so the issue is even worse. I have attempted to use wspace = x, in a variety of ways but have not had any real success.

[image: Bad plot spacing]

**the code at the top was borrowed because initially the color bars were either not appearing right or my plots were squeezed vertically.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def colorbar(mappable):
    last_axes = plt.gca()
    ax = mappable.axes
    fig = ax.figure
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    caxr = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
    cbar = fig.colorbar(mappable, cax=caxr)
    plt.sca(last_axes)
    return cbar

np.random.seed(19680801)
grid = np.random.rand(53, 51)

fields = plt.figure(figsize = [15,6])

gs0 = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)

gs00 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, 1, subplot_spec=gs0[0])

ax0 = plt.Subplot(fields, gs00[:, :])
im0 = ax0.plot(grid[0],grid[1])
ax0.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y', title='Plot1'),
ax0.grid(),
fields.add_subplot(ax0)

gs01 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 3, subplot_spec=gs0[1])
ax1 = plt.Subplot(fields, gs01[0, 0])

im1 = ax1.imshow(grid, cmap = 'inferno', interpolation = 'gaussian')
colorbar(im1)
ax1.set_title('plot'), ax1.set_xlabel('z'), ax1.set_ylabel('r')
fields.add_subplot(ax1)

ax2 = plt.Subplot(fields, gs01[0, 1])
im2 = ax2.imshow(grid, cmap = 'inferno', interpolation = 'gaussian')
colorbar(im2)
ax2.set_title('plot'), ax2.set_xlabel('z'), ax2.set_ylabel('r')
fields.add_subplot(ax2)

ax3 = plt.Subplot(fields, gs01[0, 2])
ax3.set(title='plot', xlabel='z', ylabel = 'r')
im3 = ax3.imshow(grid, cmap = 'inferno', interpolation = 'gaussian')
colorbar(im3)
ax3.set(title='plot', xlabel='z', ylabel = 'r')
fields.add_subplot(ax3)

ax4 = plt.Subplot(fields, gs01[1, 0])
im4 = ax4.imshow(grid, cmap = 'inferno', interpolation = 'gaussian')
colorbar(im4)
ax4.set(title='plot', xlabel='z', ylabel = 'r')
fields.add_subplot(ax4)

ax5 = plt.Subplot(fields, gs01[1, 1])
im5 = ax5.imshow(grid, cmap = 'inferno', interpolation = 'gaussian')
colorbar(im5)
ax5.set(title='$plot', xlabel='z', ylabel = 'r')
fields.add_subplot(ax5)

ax6 = plt.Subplot(fields, gs01[1, 2])
im6 = ax6.imshow(grid, cmap = 'inferno', interpolation = 'gaussian')
colorbar(im6)
ax6.set(title='plot', xlabel='z', ylabel = 'r')
fields.add_subplot(ax6)

plt.suptitle("GirdSpec Plot")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spacing of the right subplot was adjusted in the grid spec of gs01; second, the composition ratio of the left graph was corrected to 2/5 in the grid spec of gs0; third, `ax0.set_aspect('equal')`, The graph of the left is square.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec, GridSpecFromSubplotSpec

def colorbar(mappable):
    last_axes = plt.gca()
    ax = mappable.axes
    fig = ax.figure
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    caxr = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
    cbar = fig.colorbar(mappable, cax=caxr)
    plt.sca(last_axes)
    return cbar

np.random.seed(19680801)
grid = np.random.rand(53, 51)

fields = plt.figure(figsize = [15,6])

gs0 = GridSpec(1, 2, width_ratios=(2,5)) # update

gs00 = GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, 1, subplot_spec=gs0[0]) 

ax0 = plt.Subplot(fields, gs00[:, :])
im0 = ax0.plot(grid[0],grid[1])
ax0.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y', title='Plot1')
ax0.grid()
ax0.set_aspect('equal') # update
fields.add_subplot(ax0)

gs01 = GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 3, subplot_spec=gs0[1], wspace=0.8) # update
ax1 = plt.Subplot(fields, gs01[0, 0])

im1 = ax1.imshow(grid, cmap = 'inferno', interpolation = 'gaussian')
colorbar(im1)
ax1.set_title('plot'), ax1.set_xlabel('z'), ax1.set_ylabel('r')
fields.add_subplot(ax1)

ax2 = plt.Subplot(fields, gs01[0, 1])
im2 = ax2.imshow(grid, cmap = 'inferno', interpolation = 'gaussian')
colorbar(im2)
ax2.set_title('plot'), ax2.set_xlabel('z'), ax2.set_ylabel('r')
fields.add_subplot(ax2)

ax3 = plt.Subplot(fields, gs01[0, 2])
ax3.set(title='plot', xlabel='z', ylabel = 'r')
im3 = ax3.imshow(grid, cmap = 'inferno', interpolation = 'gaussian')
colorbar(im3)
ax3.set(title='plot', xlabel='z', ylabel = 'r')
fields.add_subplot(ax3)

ax4 = plt.Subplot(fields, gs01[1, 0])
im4 = ax4.imshow(grid, cmap = 'inferno', interpolation = 'gaussian')
colorbar(im4)
ax4.set(title='plot', xlabel='z', ylabel = 'r')
fields.add_subplot(ax4)

ax5 = plt.Subplot(fields, gs01[1, 1])
im5 = ax5.imshow(grid, cmap = 'inferno', interpolation = 'gaussian')
colorbar(im5)
ax5.set(title='$plot', xlabel='z', ylabel = 'r')
fields.add_subplot(ax5)

ax6 = plt.Subplot(fields, gs01[1, 2])
im6 = ax6.imshow(grid, cmap = 'inferno', interpolation = 'gaussian')
colorbar(im6)
ax6.set(title='plot', xlabel='z', ylabel = 'r')
fields.add_subplot(ax6)

plt.suptitle("GirdSpec Plot")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're right about `wspace` but have to use it on the second Gridspec:

```
gs01 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 3, subplot_spec=gs0[1], wspace=0.5)
```

[image]